# Dynamically loading an external xaml file's code-behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind

I've been writing applications that load xaml files dynamically using XamlReader. That way I can skin my applications in different ways, or distribute just simple xaml files to users for different amounts of functionality. Now I'm wondering if there's a way to do something similar for code-behind files. Is there a way to distribute a loose code behind file as an external file that can be dynamically loaded? I imagine no because it's code, but I thought I'd ask anyway :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can reference the C# compiler and use it to compile files dynamically. Check out the [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) class.